# Please explain $\frac{\partial }{\partial x} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} U(r + x)n(x)dx$ how do we solve this?

Tags: integration, derivatives

We are given a function $f(\cdot)$:
$$
f(\cdot ) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} U(r + x)n(x)dx
$$
Then we differentiate it with respect to $r$ and get the following result:
$$
\frac{\partial f(\cdot)}{\partial r} = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} U' n(x) dx
$$
Having almost no math background but trying to understand my textbook my question is how did we get that answer? What sources should I refer to to learn how to do this type of problem? My introductory calculus book does not seem to have similar problems.

P.S. $U(\cdot)$ and $n(x)$ are nice and continuous.

Comment: Is it really $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$? Isn't it $\frac{\partial f}{\partial r}$? That would make sense, as the integral is a function of $r$, not $x$. Well maybe the dot means, that it's a function of whatever it's function of.

Comment: @Tom83B, you are right, it is $\frac{\partial }{\partial r}$. I corrected the question.

Comment: @Tom83B so if the integral is a function of $r$, why are allowed to move differentiation operator under the integral sign?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it was meant to be a derivative with respect to $r$ then it will come inside:

$\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\int^\infty_{-\infty}U(r+x)n(x)dx=\int^\infty_{-\infty}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}U(r+x)n(x)dx=\int^\infty_{-\infty}\frac{\partial(r+x)}{\partial r}U'(r+x)n(x)dx$

$=\int^\infty_{-\infty}U'(r+x)n(x)dx$

Also the $x$ derivative would just be $0$.

Comment: Thank you! However, I do not understand why we are allowed to move differentiation operator under the integral sign in this case. What are the rules and\or could you please refer me to a book that I could read on the topic?

Comment: There is a lot of mathematics behind when you can bring the derivative in, I don't know any references off hand, but in standard exercises if you are not asked to prove it then you take it for granted, that being said, it does depend on how "nice" the functions are, but you said they are nice ones so it is okay :)

Comment: Sorry, I was getting confused with bringing derivatives into infinite sums, the criteria you need for the integral case, is that the function within the integral must have continuous partial derivatives :) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule

Comment: Thank you! Leibniz integral rule is just what I was looking for.

Comment: No worries, happy to help :)